# Sum of a particular Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider, for strictly positive and reals $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the convergent series

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^k}{k}\,e^{-\beta\,k^2}\,\sin\left(2\,\pi\,\alpha\,k\right).
$$

I am looking for any clue that may help in understanding the summation. Does someone recognize in it a notable series?

**Curiosity** . I get this series because I am computing expected values of the kind $\mathbb{E}\left[\sin(2\,\pi\,k\,u)\right]$ with $u\sim\text{N}\left(\mu,\sigma^2\right)$.

Comment: If it helps, Mathematica can't find a closed form for this sum or the equivalent integral.

Comment: Differentiate with regard to $\alpha,$ and use [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) to rewrite the new expression in terms of the [Jacobi $\theta$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function). If even this fails, then all hope is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recalling the definition of the Jacobi theta 4 function $$\theta_{4}\left(z,q\right)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(-1\right)^{n}q^{n^{2}}e^{2niz}=1+2\sum_{n\geq1}\left(-1\right)^{n}q^{n^{2}}\cos\left(2nz\right)
 $$ we have $$\int\theta_{4}\left(z,q\right)dz=z+\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n}q^{n^{2}}\sin\left(2nz\right)+C
 $$ and so $$\int_{0}^{\pi\alpha}\theta_{4}\left(z,e^{-\beta}\right)dz=\pi\alpha+\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n}e^{-\beta n^{2}}\sin\left(2n\pi\alpha\right)
 $$ and I think it's all.

Comment: xMarco: Thanks for your answer. There is something that confuses me. The $\theta_4\left(z,q\right)$ it is not defined for $q=1$ since $$\sum_{n\geq1}\left(-1\right)^{n}\cos\left(2nz\right)$$ does not converge. Nevertheless for $\beta=0$ I get that $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n}e^{-\beta n^{2}}\sin\left(2n\pi\alpha\right)$$ exists while the left side of your last equation is not defined since involves $\theta_4(z,1)$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @AlmostSureUser For $\beta =0$ you can consider $$\lim_{\beta\rightarrow0}\int_{0}^{\pi\alpha}\theta_{4}(z,e^{-\beta})dz.$$